# Как изменить поведение оператора [] при использовании указателя?

Tags: c++, g++

Имеется данная структура и определение типа указателя на эту структуру.

```
using MEMDESC = struct [[gnu::packed]] _mem_desc {
    _mem_desc *pmdNext; //8 //+0
    size_t ulSize; //8 //+8
    unsigned int uCUN; //4 //+16
    unsigned int uUUN; //4 //+20
    unsigned int smallData[1018]; //4n, максимум //+24
    unsigned int& operator[](unsigned int iInx){
        return smallData[iInx];
    }
};
using PMEMDESC = MEMDESC*;
```

`PMEMDESC pmdWork;` определяется где-то в коде.

Я могу использовать `(*pmdWork)[0].wPrev = 0;` для доступа, но сама запись выглядит коряво до нельзя. Как получить аналогичный функционал при использовании `pmdWork[0].wPrev=0`?
И для осознания корявости, при указанном решении, приведу одну строку: `hhHandle=reinterpret_cast<void*>(&(*pmdWork)[sbIndex+1]);`

Comment: А что это по-вашему должно означать? Поле `wPrew` у первого элемента массива `pmdWork` или первое поле `smallData` **какого** элемента массива `pmdWork`? (ведь `pmdWork` вполне может быть массивом!)

Comment: @Harry  я не спорю, что ситуация неоднозначная, но PMEMDESC никогда не используется как указатель на массив элементов MEMDESC.

Comment: А откуда это известно языку? :) Ладно, пишите `pmdWork->operator[](0).wPrew` :)

Comment: "Как изменить поведение оператора [] при использовании указателя?" Ответ: никак.

Comment: `MEMDESC& mdWork = *pmdWork; mdWork[0].vPrev = 0;`

Comment: @int3 pmdWork меняется, а операция `mdWork=*pmdWork;` после изменения `pmdWork` вырабатывает кривой исполняемый код с ud2, почему-то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перегружаете `operator[]` для классов, а не для указателей на них. А так, как `operator[]` должен быть нестатическим методом класса, мы не можем определить его как `int& operator[](MEMDESC* ptr, size_t idx)` в области видимости вне класса.

Вы можете выбрать один из следующих подходов:

```
struct widget
{
   int arr[10];
   int& operator[](size_t idx) { return arr[idx]; }
};

int& get(widget* ptr, size_t idx)
{
    return (*ptr)[idx];
}

int main()
{
    widget w;
    widget* wp = &w;
    // 1. Ваш вариант
    (*wp)[0] = 10;
    // 2. Тоже самое, только в обертке
    get(wp, 0) = 10;
    // 3
    wp[0][0] = 10;
    // 3 будет эквивалентно
    (*(wp + 0))[0] = 10;
    // что в свою очередь эквивалентно
    (*wp)[0] = 10;
    // 4
    wp->operator[](0) = 10;
}
```

Comment: А еще, например, `0[wp][0] = 20;` :)

Comment: Запихнуть в `using` для указателя значит никак?... А код лишь как пример (кривого) решения.

Comment: wp[0][0] = 10; - вариант